# How to keep url data when going to another page

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I have url variables that was submitted from a form from the previous page. So my url looks something like site.com/submitted.php?first_name=hello&last_name=bye.

Now I am using a link to keep my submitted variables while I go to my second page
    `<a href="secondPage.php?first_name=hello&last_name=bye>pageLink</a>`

On this second page, it's basically a drop-down using the select tag with a submit button that generates a table from mysql server which then links back into the same page. It looks like:

```
<FORM ACTION="secondPage.php?first_name=hello&last_name=bye" METHOD="GET">
    <select name='selectedOption' >
        <option value="op1">option1</option>  
        <option value="op2">option2</option>  
        <option value="op3">option3</option>  
    </select>
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE = "Search">
</FORM>
```

But lets say I choose option1 and submit, my url does not keep the variables first_name and last_name but it just replaces it :

```
secondPage.php?selectedOption=op1
```

instead of:

```
secondPage.php?first_name=hello&last_name=bye&selectedOption=op1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use hidden fields to remember them.. `<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $_GET['first_name']; ?>`

Comment: If you use Tim's method, please HTML encode your `$_GET` values. Otherwise, you could end up with broken or, worse, compromised pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ON THE SECOND PAGE**. In form make two hidden fields `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['first_name'] ?>" name="first_name"/>` and

```
<input type="hidden" value=""<?php echo $_REQUEST['last_name'] ?>"" name="last_name"/>
```

my suggestion use `post` method

Comment: Ehhm... XSS ftw. `""/><script>alert('foo');</script><input type="hidden" value=""`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you want to pass data around but here is a suggestion to get the values you want with php.

Change this:

`<FORM ACTION="secondPage.php?first_name=hello&last_name=bye" METHOD="GET>`

to this:

`<form action="secondPage.php" METHOD="post">`

Your code for `secondPage.php` coud look something like this:

```
// the 'if' statements aren't necessary. just an idea for simple server-side
// validation

if(isset($_REQUEST['selectedOption']) && $_REQUEST['selectedOption'] != ''){
    $option = $_REQUEST['selectedOption'];
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['first_name']) && $_REQUEST['first_name'] != ''){
    $fname = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['last_name']) && $_REQUEST['last_name'] != ''){
    $lname = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
}
```

All the values you need to do whatever with are now in `$option`, `$fname`, and `$lname`

You say your new to php, welcome :), and don't ever trust user input. You should take some time and read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Hope some of this helps and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I've been working myself with something exactly like that, but I've found a great solution and a great approach in my own opinion.. let me give you some bit and piece of code as an example if you don't mind ^_^..

to be organised and clear what you did is : -

```
##**FIRST PAGE** : -
the url: - secondPage.php?first_name=hello&last_name=bye <--- this was the result..

Then you travelled to the 2nd page: - <-- result was still associated

##**SECOND PAGE** : -

$firstname = $_GET['first_name'];
$lastname= $_GET['last_name'];
<FORM ACTION="secondPage.php?first_name=<?php echo $firstname; ?>&last_name=<?php echo $lastname ?>" METHOD="POST">
    <select name='selectedOption' >
        <option value="op1">option1</option>  
        <option value="op2">option2</option>  
        <option value="op3">option3</option>  
    </select>
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" name ="submit" VALUE = "Search">
</FORM>

##**THIRD PAGE** The page that the form is going to go to: -


$option = $_GET ['selectedOption'];
// you can also get the other data on this page through same method i've done on page two..
```